# create a polynomial matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, polynomial-math

I have got vector of coefficients v=[v1, v2, v3] (added by user).
I want to create a polynomial in a function. I would like to have a function fun(x), which solution will be my polynomial. After that I want to have a graph of this polynomial.
This is my idea but it doesn't work. Could you have any ideas how to improve it?

```
function [v] = createPolynomial(x)

r = length(v);
fun=0;
for i=r:1
    fun=fun+v(i)*x.^(r-1); 

end
```

Comment: So `v` is an input to `createPolynomial`, right? so the function definition should be `function [out] = createPolynomial(v, x)`

Comment: There is a build in `polyval` to evaluate a polynom.

Comment: Well I would like to write my own polynom, 
function f = createPolynomial(v,x)
will be correct?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Your code looks ok otherwise.

Comment: There is something wrong... Matlab said: "Too many input arguments."

Comment: WHen I use it like this: fplot(@(x0)stworzWielomian(x0,wsp),[-7,7], 'p');

Comment: Hmm, but how is that code related to the questions? what is `stworzWielomian`? Is that `createPolynomial`?

Comment: So `stworzWielomian` needs to be defined as `function y = stworzWielomian(x, arg)` in `stworzWielomian.m`

Comment: Sorry it was fplot(@(x0)createPolynomial(v,x),[-7,7], 'p');

Comment: and header of the function looks like that: function f = createPolynomial(v,x)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close! Is this what you want?

```
function f = createPoly(v,x)
n = length(v);
f = 0;
for ii = 1:n
    f = f + v(ii)*x.^(n-ii+1);
end
end

f = createPoly([1 2 3 5],4)
f =
   113
    %% (1*4^3) + (2*4^2) + (3*4^1) + (5*4^0) = 113
```

Some errors in your code:

```
function [v] = createPolynomial(x)
```

As I understand it, you want both `v` and `x` as inputs to your function, and get a value back. Then you must do `function value = createPolynomial(v, x)`, where `value`will be the output variable.

```
fun=fun+v(i)*x.^(r-1);
```

I guess this is just a typo, but `.^r-1` is a constant value. You probably want the exponent to go from `n, n-1, ... 1, 0` In that case you want `r-i`. And if I don't point it out, someone else will definitely do: Using `i` as a variable in MATLAB is not good practice if you are sometimes dealing with complex numbers.

And I guess you know this, but I'll say it anyway: You m-file must have the same name as you function.

If you want to input `x` as a vector, you must initialize `f` as a vector having the same length as `x`. That is:

```
f = zeros(1,length(x));
```

Now, you can do:

```
f = createPoly([1 2 3 5],1:5)
f =   
    11
    27
    59
   113
   195
```

Answer (score 0):

you define coefficients in the following form of variable p

% example : 
          p =[ 2 1 3] % coefficients

```
      x=0:0.2:5; % values at which it is to be evaluated
      y=polyval(p, x);
      plot(x,y)
```

polyval is provided in standard matlab, it evaluates the polynomial. see help polyval